# Running a Makefile on Raspberry Pi3, installation problems

Tags: makefile, raspberry-pi3

let me start off by saying this is an entirely new world to me so forgive any improper use of terminology.

The problem in a nutshell, I was given the file which is used to run a GUI for controlling a motor. The UI was created in Qt Creator. After numerous google searches and trial and error I learned how to run the Makefile on the Raspberry Pi3 device. This code is in working order and should not need any modifications to the code itself persay, it is just a matter of installing the right packages and typing the correct commands.

These are the steps I am getting to and the resulting output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/BasicInterface $ make

cp source/Collection.py build/Collection.py
cp source/main_release.py build/main_release.py
cp source/utilities.py build/utilities.py
cp source/Calibration.py build/Calibration.py
cp source/main_debug.py build/main_debug.py
cp source/archive.py build/archive.py
cp source/MotorControl.py build/MotorControl.py
cp source/MainCanvas.py build/MainCanvas.py
cp source/Report.py build/Report.py
cp source/MainWindow.py build/MainWindow.py
cp source/LoadCell.py build/LoadCell.py
cp source/Analysis.py build/Analysis.py
pyrcc5 resources/resources_rc.qrc -o build/resources_rc.py
pyuic5 resources/Ui_MainWindow.ui > build/Ui_MainWindow.py
pyuic5 resources/Ui_About.ui > build/Ui_About.py
python3 -m zipapp -p "/usr/bin/env python3" build -m main_release:main -o main_release.pyz
```

This is the Makefile file:

```
SRC  = $(wildcard source/*.py)
OBJ  = $(subst source,build,$(SRC))
OBJ += build/resources_rc.py
OBJ += build/Ui_MainWindow.py
OBJ += build/Ui_About.py

RCS  = $(wildcard resources/embed/*)
RCS += $(wildcard resources/dynamic/*)

PYTHON = python3
FLAGS  = -m zipapp -p "/usr/bin/env python3" build

all:     release
release: main_release.pyz
debug:   main_debug.pyz
install: main_release.pyz

.PRECIOUS:     $(OBJ)
.PHONY:        clean
.PHONY:        install

%.pyz: $(OBJ)
    $(PYTHON) $(FLAGS) -m $(basename $@):main -o $@

build/%.py: source/%.py
    cp $< $@

build/%.py: resources/%.qrc $(RCS)
    pyrcc5 $< -o $@

build/%.py: resources/%.ui
    pyuic5 $< > $@

resources/dynamic/about.html: support/writeAbout.sh
    ./support/writeAbout.sh resources/dynamic/about.html

clean:
    -rm $(OBJ)
    -rm main_*.pyz
    -rm -rf build/__pycache__

install:
    mkdir -p $(HOME)/.irisEngineering
    install main_release.pyz $(HOME)/.irisEngineering/AdhesionTester.pyz
    install resources/embed/icon.svg $(HOME)/.irisEngineering/
    envsubst <support/AdhesionTester.desktop >$(HOME)/Desktop/AdhesionTester.desktop
```

Basically it is not creating the directory (unless I'm looking in the wrong spot) and I do not see the application anywhere. I'm not sure if the information I have provided will suffice in helping me, but please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Which directory is supposed to be created? Are you able to determine which part is failing?

Comment: There are no errors, the first code I posted is every output I receive after entering "make". At the last few lines in the Makefile there is the mkdir ... /.irisEngineering, this is the directory to be created. I think there could be an error with the resources_rc file as well. I ran into the issue where I would get an error stating `No resources in resource description. Makefile:29: recipe for target 'build/resources_rc.py' failed make: *** [build/resources_rc.py] Error 1.` To fix this I found another post to make a resource file and essentially I opened the UI in Qt Designer and created one.

Comment: For the resource file I added prefix then added the icon as the prefix and honestly I feel like this might be the problem.

Comment: Have you tested without rc.py? Using only resources.rc? My point here, is are you sure it requires the `.py`? Typically resource files will use the `.rc` extension, not always though.

Comment: An idea on the directory side of things, add: `echo $(HOME)` as the first step, verify that HOME is what you expect it to be, if it is, then try `cd $(HOME)` then `mkdir -p .irisEngineering`. Also try with -pv, -v being for verbose, you should see a message stating the directory has been created.

Comment: Is the resources file only used to add an emblem to the application icon, or is there more to this resources file that I am missing? I guess I just deleted all line referring to the resources file and it did not change anything.

Comment: I tried adding the mentioned steps, nothing changed in the output.

Comment: Well I'm sorry for wasting your time, rookie here and apparently you have to type `make install` for it to install... I've managed to get it onto the desktop now it just won't open